# Static local variable initialisation in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, initialization, c++03

Suppose there is a function (member function possibly)

```
SomeType foo()
{
    static SomeType var = generateVar();
    return var;
}
```

How `var` will be initialised if `foo` will be called 'for first time' from multiple threads simultaneously?

1. Is it guaranteed that `generateVar()` will be called only once in any scenario (if used of course)?
2. Is it guaranteed that `foo` will return the same value when called multiple times in any scenario?
3. Is there a difference in behaviour for primitive or non-primitive types?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Concerning C++03:**

The abstract machine defined by the C++03 Standard does not contain a formal definition of what a *thread* is, and what the outcome of a program should be if an object is accessed concurrently.

There is no notion of *synchronization primitive*, ordering of operations performed in different threads, *data race*, and so on. Therefore, by definition, every multi-threaded C++03 program contains undefined behavior.

Of course, in practice implementations do provide a documented behavior, but there is nothing in the Standard that specifies what this behavior should be. Therefore, I would say it depends on your compiler.

The rest of the answer will focus on C++11, which does define the semantics of concurrent operations.

**Concerning C++11:**

> Is it guaranteed that `generateVar()` will be called only once in any scenario (if used of course)?

No, not in any scenario.

The initialization of `var` is guaranteed to be thread-safe, so `generateVar()` won't be entered concurrently, but if an exception is thrown by `generateVar()`, or by the copy constructor or move constructor of `SomeType` (if `SomeType` is a UDT, of course), then initialization will be re-attempted the next time the flow of execution enters the declaration - which means `generateVar()` will get called again.

Per paragraph 6.7/4 of the C++11 Standard on the initialization of block-scope variables with *static storage duration*:

> [...] If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
>   is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. If control enters
>   the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for
>   completion of the initialization. If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being
>   initialized, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Concerning your next question:

> Is it guaranteed that foo will return the same value when called multiple times in any scenario?

If it will manage to return a value (see above), then yes.

> Is there a difference in behaviour for primitive or non-primitive types?

No, there isn't, except that there is no such a thing as a copy constructor or move constructor for primitive types, so there is also no risk that copy-initialization will result in throwing an exception (unless of course `generateVar()` throws).

Comment: "initialization will be attempted next time"? How is this achieved? AFAIK a static variable is initialized when the module is loaded and this happens only once during the process lifetime.

Comment: @Devolus: A static variable in a block scope is initialized when its declaration is met by the execution flow. I added a quote from the Standard

Comment: @AndyProwl: thanks for you answer. Can you please clarify what will happen in C++98?

Comment: Please remember that VS (2012, current version) only supports a subset of C++11 and not these 'magic statics'. So for a significant portion of the programming world this isn't yet applicable in real world code :-(

Comment: @Andrew: C++98, as well as C++03, does not define the notion of "thread", so every multithreaded program has (formally) undefined behavior. I guess everything else is implementation-specific

Comment: @Andrew: I expanded my answer

Comment: @AndyProwl: you might want to touch on re-entrancy. Should `generateVar` call on `foo` during initialization of `var`, bad things would happen. On gcc, a specific exception is generated.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Indeed, that's undefined behavior, but the last sentence of the paragraph from the Standard I quoted in the answer does mention that