# C++ static member deconstructor called multiple times

Tags: c++, object, constructor, static

I have a Properties class which loads some properties from a file. I want to have only one instance of the properties and to be accessible from all classes. Here is what i did in a very Java spirit:

```
class Properties{
public:
    static Properties getInstance();
    ~Properties();
private:
    Properties();
    static Properties instance;
}
```

So the Class has a static member of itself which can me accessed from the function getInstance(). I then have various other functions to get the properties from the object. E.g.

```
Properties::getInstance().getUseDepthInpainting();
```

The weird thing is that only the first time I try to access a property I get the right value. Other than that I get zero values. I then proceeded to put a print statement in the constructor and one in the deconstructor. While, as expected, the constructor is called only the first time I call getInstance(), the deconstructor gets called every time time the getInstance() is called.. Can someone explain why this is happening, and what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: While your immediate problem is probably the copies you're creating, I'd like to point out that this is likely an abuse of the singleton pattern for something that shouldn't be a singleton. A singleton should be used only when there's a technical limit to the number of instances, for example when abstracting a finite physical resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton works on 3 ingredients:

- private reference
- private constructor
- public creational function ("instance", "getInstance" etc.)

The trick goes like this:

1. call the creational function
2. the creational function checks if the pointer is null
3. if the pointer is null - create new instance on it
4. return the pointer

in your snippet the isntance is not held by a pointer, but is a full-standing object. if you change instance to be from the type 
`Properties*` and `getInstance()` to return  `Properties*` (or `Properties&`) I guess the problem will be solved

Currently, at the verge of 2016, the correct way to write a singletone is as follows:

```
class Singleton{

private:
  static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance;
  static std::once_flag onceFlag;
  Singleton();

public:
  static Singleton& getInstance(){
    std::call_once(onceFlag,[&]{
       instance = std::unique_ptr<Singleton>(new Singleton());    
    });
    return *instance;
  }

};
```

Comment: Why so complicated `getInstance`? What's the advantage compared to just returning a reference to a static object?

Comment: avoid multi-threaded problems. avoid potential memory leaks problems

Comment: @DavidHaim That is outdated. C++11 has magic statics that do that for you and since you stretched "the verge of 2016" one can assume 2011 has passed.

Comment: I'm not sure that Mayers' technik (static instance on a function) is mutil-threaded safe by the standard yet.

Comment: @DavidHaim "*If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization*" That seems pretty clear cut to me. Can you clarify your doubts?

Comment: is this the 11 standard or the 14?

Comment: @DavidHaim according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734966/static-local-variable-initialisation-in-multithreaded-environment), it's in c++11. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the standard myself, but the wording *is* in the working draft N3242 which was before the release of c++11 and in the standard drafts after the release.

Comment: Why saving only pointer in static segment, but instance on the heap?

Answer (score 2):

Your `getInstance` method is returning the properties by value, which means you return a copy of the actual instance. It is this copy that is being destroyed every time it goes out of scope.

The solution is returning a reference to the `instance` object, by changing the signature of your function to:

```
static Properties& getInstance();
```

It is probably even better, if your object is read-only, to make it a `const` reference so your caller can't go messing about in your Properties object:

```
static const Properties& getInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

> static member deconstructor called multiple times

Nope, the destructor of the static member is only called once.

> While, as expected, the constructor is called only the first time I call getInstance(), the deconstructor gets called every time time the getInstance() is called.. Can someone explain why this is happening, and what is the correct way of doing this?

The destructor is called for each copy of `instance` that are returned by `getInstance` when they get destroyed. The default constructor is called only once: The other instances are created using the copy-constructor.

It seems that you're attempting to implement the singleton pattern. In that case you should be returning a reference to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

> While, as expected, the constructor is called only the first time I
>   call getInstance(), the deconstructor gets called every time time the
>   getInstance() is called.

Default constructor called once. All other times there are calls of copy constructor.

Delete copy and move constructors and assignment operators.

This is a correct singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton & Instance()
    {
        // Since it's a static variable, if the class has already been created,
        // It won't be created again.
        // And it **is** thread-safe in C++11.

        static Singleton myInstance;

        // Return a reference to our instance.
        return myInstance;
    }

    // delete copy and move constructors and assign operators
    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;             // Copy construct
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;                  // Move construct
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;  // Copy assign
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;      // Move assign

    // Any other public methods

protected:
    Singleton()
    {
         // Constructor code goes here.
    }

    ~Singleton()
    {
         // Destructor code goes here.
    }

     // And any other protected methods.
}
```

From [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Singleton#Thread_safe_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29).